# Adding serial data to list causes IndexError

Tags: python-3.x, list, serial-port

I am reading serial data from the arduino, then i filter them, and i place the data in lists.

```
def readSerial():
    global after_id, found_coordinate, coordinate, sensors
    while ser.in_waiting:
            ser_bytes = ser.readline()
            ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
            if "SENSOR COORDINATE" in ser_bytes:
               found_coordinate = True
               coordinate = int(ser_bytes.split("=")[1].strip())
               print("Coordinate: ",coordinate)
            if "MEASURED RESISTANCE" in ser_bytes and found_coordinate:
               found_coordinate = False
               resistance = float(ser_bytes.split("=")[1].split("kOhm")[0].strip())
               print("Resistance: ",resistance)
               sensors[coordinate].append(resistance) # Append the resistance value, to the appropriate sensor list
    after_id=root.after(50,readSerial)
```

I filter the data, and if i see the text "SENSOR COORDINATE" in a line, i parse that data.
Then i also grab the resistance for that sensor, and with the `append()` line, i place that value to the list with the index as the resistance coordinate value i grabbed earlier.

However, after i few times i receive data, then i come across an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Here is the full terminal output and error:

```
Coordinate:  0
Resistance:  3.2
Coordinate:  1
Resistance:  3.2
Coordinate:  2
Resistance:  3.23
Coordinate:  3
Resistance:  3.31
Coordinate:  4
Resistance:  3.3
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__i
nit__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__i
nit__.py", line 804, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "tkinterWithPortsExperiment.py", line 103, in readSerial
    sensors[coordinate].append(resistance) # Append the resistance value, to the
 appropriate sensor list
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: In the fifth iteration, where `coordinate == 4`, it tries to access the 4th index of `sensors`. Since `sensors` has only four elements (with maximum index 3), it'll raise an `IndexError`. I don't know what your `sensors` is holding in your logic so I can't help further.

Comment: I cant believe i did not notice that and i made usch a dumb mistake.. Thank you very much. If you want, you can place a normal answer so i can upvote and mark it as the selected answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fifth iteration, where `coordinate == 4`, it tries to access the 4th index of `sensors`. Since `sensors` has only four elements (with maximum index 3), it'll raise the `IndexError` you're getting.

You can review your logic to checking the length of `sensors` before acessing some index of it:

```py
if "MEASURED RESISTANCE" in ser_bytes and found_coordinate:
    found_coordinate = False
    resistance = float(ser_bytes.split("=")[1].split("kOhm")[0].strip())
    if coordinate < len(sensors):
        sensors[coordinate].append(resistance)
    else:
        # do some other logic
```